# How to align items in material-ui App Bar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm simply looking to align the items in my navbar something like this (but switching out the 'Buy on App Store' for a Search Box):

[image]

I'm currently taking 'inspiration' from this material-ui component: https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#SearchAppBar.js

For some reason I'm getting all of my items bunched up to the left instead of some sort of sensible alignment:

[image]

How do I get my items to align properly? Is it something my component may be inheriting? There isn't really any parents components, it's imported directly into App.js.

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar'
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignedInLinks from './SignedInLinks';
import SignedOutLinks from './SignedOutLinks';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    link: {
        color: 'white',
        textDecoration: 'none'
    },
    root: {
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        display: 'none',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            display: 'block',
        },
    },
    search: {
        position: 'relative',
        borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
        backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
        },
        marginLeft: 0,
        width: '100%',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
            width: 'auto',
        },
    },
    searchIcon: {
        width: theme.spacing(7),
        height: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        pointerEvents: 'none',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    inputRoot: {
        color: 'inherit',
    },
    inputInput: {
        padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 7),
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
        width: '100%',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: 120,
            '&:focus': {
                width: 200,
            },
        },
    },
}));


const Navbar = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const links = loggedIn ? <SignedInLinks profile={profile} /> : <SignedOutLinks />;
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <Link to='/' className={classes.link}>
                        <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" noWrap>
                            MyApp
                        </Typography>
                    </Link>
                    {links}
                    <div className={classes.search}>
                        <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
                            <SearchIcon />
                        </div>
                        <InputBase
                            placeholder="Search…"
                            classes={{
                                root: classes.inputRoot,
                                input: classes.inputInput,
                            }}
                            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    )
}
```

***edit:***

Removing { links } in response to a comment but I still get the same issue:

[image]

***edit2:***

It seems removing the `<Link>` elements allows my search box to go to the correct place. Do we know why? My problem is that I need my element to route the user to the home page if they click on the title

Comment: The problem seem to be the `SignedInLinks` and `SignedOutLinks` components, they look like `<ul>` elements and that is their default style.

Comment: @Titus If I remove the link I still get the same issue. I'll edit the original post to show.

Comment: If I remove the <Link to='/' className={classes.link}>...stuff..<Link> it seems to render correctly!! But...I need the <Link> elements

Comment: Try to add the link back and give it the class `title` (`<Link to='/' className={classes.title}>....`)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add `div` container like so:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="search">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: space-between
}
```